# AllDay event not triggering in Fullcalendar Scheduler 6.1.8

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, bootstrap-5, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-6

I am using Fullcalendar Scheduler version 6.1.8. In previous version I was able to click on allDaySlot and triggered select event. In this latest version when I click the allDaySlot, nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvYLGEj. If you have a problem still, please provide a [mre] of the problem within your question, using your code. See also [ask] - it's very rare that we can help to debug your code without seeing it! Thanks.

Comment: I have checked again and found the exact spot of a problem. It is related to resources. I load them dynamically via URL as JSON - for example: [{"id":"3","title":"TEN1"},{"id":"4","title":"TEN2"}]. Resources load just fine and I can select any hourly slot, but cannot click on a full day. However, If I replace the dynamic resource and load static, it works. Any idea?